# How to listening for realtime updates using FirebaseFirestore, SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, chat, message

I make ChatApp by SwiftUI-FirebaseFirestore. I run 2 simulators at the same time and if user A sends a message to user B, I have to reload user B's interface to display. I want it to be automatic and show up immediately so what's the idea to do?

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: It sounds like you're not yet [listening for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to the data. But as lorem ipsem commented, it's hard to say more without seeing a minimal repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a snapshot listener. Effectively it's treated the same as with any other documents but it has a closure that allows you to respond to updated events on a particular document. It's general usage is this.

```
db.collection("cities").document("SF")
.addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
  guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
    print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
    return
  }
  guard let data = document.data() else {
    print("Document data was empty.")
    return
  }
  print("Current data: \(data)")
}
```

You should be able to look at the document snapshot to determine any changes in data, then respond to those changes. In your case you would reload the view.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: It works well. Your answer is exactly what I'm looking for. I replaced ".getDocuments" with ".addSnapshotListener". Thank you so much.